# GCP gcloud API filtering tags for compute instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to find all VMs in a specific project that have a particular tag.
This works

```
gcloud compute instances list --project myproject --filter="(name=myvm) AND --filter="tags.items~*ngf*"
```

But taking out the VM name does not work

```
gcloud compute instances list --project myproject --filter="tags.items~*ngf*"
```

The error message is

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Filter expression RE pattern [*ngf*]: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Any ideas? I tried using labels in the filter rather than tags.items but that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: Doing `gcloud compute instances describe` I noticed the VM I created with `create-with-container` and `--labels` doesn't actually have the labels I assigned.

Comment: just as a kind reminder take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is due to the regular expression you are using.

> `*` Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’, ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.

You can check the following [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-syntax) for more information about the regular expressions.

Regarding your request:

> I am trying to find all VMs in a specific project that have a particular tag.

Please try with the following command:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="(tags.items ~ <<YOUR-NETWORK-TAG>>*)" --project <<MY-PROJECT>>
```

or

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="(tags.items=<<YOUR-NETWORK-TAG>>)" --project <<MY-PROJECT>>
```

Now for labels you can use something like:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="(tags.items=<<YOUR-NETWORK-TAG>>) AND (labels.<<MY-LABEL>>:*)" --project <<MY-PROJECT>>
```

You might check this link to find more examples : [gcloud topic filters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters)